# Encoding a GPX file such that it's accepted by the /matchroute endpoint of the Here API

Tags: matlab, encoding, here-api, http-get, here-maps-rest

I am trying to call the resource [`/matchroute`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/resource-matchroute-request.html) via a GET request.
However, I can't figure out how to encode the GPX file so that the resource accepts my request: I always receive HTTP error 400 as a response from the Here server.

As exemplary data I used the following file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0 
http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/0/gpx.xsd">
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="51.10177" lon="0.39349"/>
      <trkpt lat="51.10181" lon="0.39335"/>
      <trkpt lat="51.10255" lon="0.39366"/>
      <trkpt lat="51.10398" lon="0.39466"/>
      <trkpt lat="51.10501" lon="0.39533"/>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
</gpx>
```

that I got from the [this example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html).

I encoded this file using MATLAB's function `matlab.net.base64encode` which yielded the following base64-encoded string:

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+PGdweCB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAieG1sbnM6eHNpPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8y
MDAxL1hNTFNjaGVtYS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy50b3BvZ3JhZml4LmNvbS9HUFgvMS8wInhzaTpz
Y2hlbWFMb2NhdGlvbj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy50b3BvZ3JhZml4LmNvbS9HUFgvMS8wIGh0dHA6Ly93d3cudG9wb2dyYWZp
eC5jb20vR1BYLzEvMC9ncHgueHNkIj48dHJrPjx0cmtzZWc+PHRya3B0IGxhdD0iNTEuMTAxNzciIGxvbj0iMC4zOTM0
OSIvPjx0cmtwdCBsYXQ9IjUxLjEwMTgxIiBsb249IjAuMzkzMzUiLz48dHJrcHQgbGF0PSI1MS4xMDI1NSIgbG9uPSIw
LjM5MzY2Ii8+PHRya3B0IGxhdD0iNTEuMTAzOTgiIGxvbj0iMC4zOTQ2NiIvPjx0cmtwdCBsYXQ9IjUxLjEwNTAxIiBs
b249IjAuMzk1MzMiLz48L3Rya3NlZz48L3Ryaz48L2dweD4=
```

However, as stated before, the HERE server consistently responds with HTTP-error 400 to my request

```
https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}&routemode=car&file=...
```

where "..." equals the above mentioned base64-encoded string.

**Question:** Could anyone please provide a code sample showing how to encode the above mentioned GPX file correctly (ideally in MATLAB language) so that the `/matchroute` resource is able to respond?

---

Remarks:

If I use the base64 string

```
UEsDBBQAAAAIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAc2FtcGxlLXRyYWNlLmdweIXPTQuCMBwG8HufQnZv%2F605S0k9dj
EIungdZjpSJ27kPn6%2BRBgYXcYYv2cPzzG2deU8805L1YSIYoLiaHMsWvv9uBlYowOrZYhKY9oAoO973DOsugJ2hFBI
z8k1K%2FNabGWjjWiy%2FJ36ShjVqqITd2lxpmo4XVKgMP6vZaCneKIyYabivzHnr4BhCbb6hoZRpnvMp86L%2BdIapx
ImRJxiSuh%2Bj5xq7CWY%2Bcz1EaypA10qxlfVjvOl8rxVxfzDQrk%2FFCfLRs7YpOCzA%2BZd49LoBVBLAQIUABQAAA
AIANmztEQSwaeZzwAAAM8BAAAQAAAAAAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAABzYW1wbGUtdHJhY2UuZ3B4UEsFBgAAAAABAAEAPgAAAP
0AAAAAAA%3D%3D
```

from [this example](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/quick-start-gps-trace-route.html) the GET request works. However, I couldn't figure out how to reproduce this encoding myself so that I am able to encode my own data accordingly.

Link to the Here API definition: https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/resource-matchroute-request.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two base64 strings I can tell you the fundamental difference between them - the first one (which doesn't work) is **unescaped** whereas the second one (which works) *is*.

You can convert between the two formats manually using various online tools like [this one](http://www.utilities-online.info/urlencode/). The escaped version of the non-working base64 string, in case you want to test it, is:

```
PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIj8+PGdweCB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAieG1sbnM6eHNpPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8y
%0AMDAxL1hNTFNjaGVtYS1pbnN0YW5jZSJ4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy50b3BvZ3JhZml4LmNvbS9HUFgvMS8wInhza
Tpz%0AY2hlbWFMb2NhdGlvbj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy50b3BvZ3JhZml4LmNvbS9HUFgvMS8wIGh0dHA6Ly93d3cudG9wb2
dyYWZp%0AeC5jb20vR1BYLzEvMC9ncHgueHNkIj48dHJrPjx0cmtzZWc+PHRya3B0IGxhdD0iNTEuMTAxNzciIGxvbj0
iMC4zOTM0%0AOSIvPjx0cmtwdCBsYXQ9IjUxLjEwMTgxIiBsb249IjAuMzkzMzUiLz48dHJrcHQgbGF0PSI1MS4xMDI1
NSIgbG9uPSIw%0ALjM5MzY2Ii8+PHRya3B0IGxhdD0iNTEuMTAzOTgiIGxvbj0iMC4zOTQ2NiIvPjx0cmtwdCBsYXQ9I
jUxLjEwNTAxIiBs%0Ab249IjAuMzk1MzMiLz48L3Rya3NlZz48L3Ryaz48L2dweD4%3D
```

I'm not an expert on this, but as I understand, you need to URL-encode strings only when you want to paste them as-is into the web path of your browser (read about "URL Params"). If you construct your HTTP requests *the right way*™ (by this I mean specify the headers of the request and the key-value pairs correctly), you shouldn't have to worry about URL-encoding at all, since the tool that you're using (in this case, MATLAB) should take care of the conversion for you.

Unfortunately, I cannot test this theory, as I have no access to the discussed API - but I am fairly certain that this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

The documentation seems to be incomplete. You can check [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/resource-matchroute-request.html) for additional information. Several ways I solved this:

- Use filetype='CSV' or filtetype='GPX' in parameter. It says the filetype is guessed if passed, that is actually not true. After passing an XML file the API told me my file didn't look like a 'CSV'
- Compression is OPTIONAL, I suggest to avoid it completely I could not find a suitable compression either. It works fine with plain base64 encoding.
- I suggest to actually use CSV because the XML actually returns parsing errors.

In python

```
data='''latitude,longitude
51.10177,0.39349
'''

r = requests.get('https://rme.api.here.com/2/matchroute.json?app_id={APP_ID}&app_code={APP_CODE}&routemode=car&file={file}&filetype={filetype}'.format(
      APP_ID=os.getenv('HERE_APP_ID'),
      APP_CODE=os.getenv('HERE_APP_CODE'),
      filetype='CSV',
      file=base64.b64encode(data.encode()).decode()
))
```